# Skype application is not running

Tags: android, eclipse, skype

When I added a button it should take me to skype application to a user (name_here) .. if Skype didn't exist on my mobile, it goes to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skype.raider

The code is

```
raskypelink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                   if (uri.contains("https://www.skype.com/" )) {
                        String name_here = "name_here";
                        String uri1 = "skype://Page/" + name_here;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri1));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        String skype = "skype";
                        String uri1 = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skype.raider" + skype;
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri1));
                        startActivity(i);
                    } 
                } 
            });
```

Please help!

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For IF
```

Android Docs - http://developer.skype.com/skype-uris/skype-uri-tutorial-android

```
For ELSE
```

Change from

```
String uri1 = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skype.raider" + skype;
```

to
Remove `+ skype`

```
String uri1 = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skype.raider";
```

Comment: It goes to play google, that's the second part, thank you, but it doesn't go to the first part, there is a name that I want to go to

Comment: For example, I have Skype running under my name, the button link tells me about another name so I can add and talk to him

Comment: is the first condition for skype install or not?

Comment: Could you tell me if 1st condition true then what should happened as per your code

Comment: Ok, I have a mobile with Skype application, if I click on the button link (if) it will run Skype application to a person (name_here) .... if Skype application not on my mobile, (else) it to goes to play google to download Skaype.

Comment: The (else) was fixed by you but the (if) still

Comment: It's like, send a msg to someone else using Skype